# IMP-00010 not a valid export file, header failed verification in Oracle Import

Tags: oracle, oracle-dump, oracle-export-dump

I have export DMP files which are exported using the exp command from oracle version 11.2.0.4.0.  I want to import the file in my oracle version 11.2.0.2.0. But during import I am getting an error as `'IMP-00010 not a valid export file, header failed verification'`.
The export dump par file has the following information :

```
USERID=TEST_CONFIG/TEST_CONFIG@Ik567G   
OWNER=TEST_CONFIG   
LOG=test01.log   
FILE=test01.dmp   
INDEXES=Y   
CONSTRAINTS=Y   
GRANTS=Y   
COMPRESS=Y   
FULL=N   
ROWS=Y   
CONSISTENT=Y   
BUFFER=80200   
FEEDBACK=500
```

And the import DMP test_config par file has the following information :

```
LOG=TEST_CONFIG.log   
FILE=test01.dmp   
FROM USER=TEST_CONFIG   
FULL=n   
ROWS=n  
 INDEXES=n  
 CONSTRAINTS=y   
IGNORE=y
```

I am running the import using following command :

```
imp TEST_CONFIG/TEST_CONFIG PARFILE=test_config.par   
imp TEST_CONFIG/TEST_CONFIG PARFILE=test_config.par
```

I tried to export and import many times and it works for me previously. As we have a different servers and databases now and When I compared and open the previous export file, it's showing the version `EXPORT:V11.02.00` where I am able to import but now for the new export it's showing the version `EXPORT:V12.01.00`. So it looks compatibility issue.

Comment: I think you're looking for `impdp` instead of `imp`

Comment: no not impdp i am exporting the complete dump...i am using exp/imp utility

Comment: Ok, but I don't understand why. You can `expdp full=Y` too. https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g

Comment: Is your dump file in the correct location? I believe the exp utility needs a full path or it defaults to the $ORACLE_HOME/dbs directory. If you didn't move your dump file to the proper location, it may not be able to find it.

Comment: yes the dump file is in the right path and i tried export/import many times and it was working for me. The only changed as i mentioned in my question is versions are different now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMP-00010: not a valid export file, header failed verification. This would give you the impression that something is wrong with the file you are trying to import. I got the same error but it was just STUPID Oracle being stupid. There was nothing wrong with my file.
    imp user/password@server/service FILE=mydumpfile.dmp
The above command gave the error from my client PC but worked perfectly if I ran it from the server using a remote desktop connection.

Answer (score 2):

> IMP-00010: not a valid export file, header failed verification.

Today I got this one when trying to import a 12.0.2 dmp file into a 11.2.0
database. When opening the dumpfile in Ultraedit there is a version number 12.0.2 or something in the first line.

I suspected this number to be the cause for IMP-00010 and **changed it manually to 11.0.2**, saved the dumpfile, and the imp succeeded.

Obviously imp only checks the version number in line 1, the imp utility itself seemes to be unchanged, at least between this two versions of the oracle database.

Answer (score 2):

The same issue occur for me when I tried to import DB dump which was exported from Oracle 11.2.0.4 into the Oracle 11.2.0.2.0 version with imp command. It gave me the exact same error. But, When I tried to import dump file into Oracle 12.1.0.2.0 it worked fine.

The issue was due to Oracle older version cannot properly identify the newer version dump. Therefore you have to try dump file with newer Oracle version. If you are import and export between different Oracle version read their [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-BAA3B679-A758-4D55-9820-432D9EB83C68.htm#SUTIL110).

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-BAA3B679-A758-4D55-9820-432D9EB83C68.htm#SUTIL110

Answer (score 1):

if you have a network connection between these two databases
then use the first server to execute the import command on the second database server.

you have to be careful when executing imp command, be very sure that you targeted the second database with imp command.

Answer (score -1):

You Export the dump from version V12.01.00 and try to import it into version V11.02.00

Use

expdp username/password version=11.02 dumpfile=filename.dmp logfile=filename.log

impdp username/password dumpfile=filename.dmp logfile=filename.log

Comment: this will not work if you provide manually in expdp command version..there is way i found where you can change the version directly in the dmp file and then run the expdp command